# Issue with publishing "related items" from Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor

I have a Sitecore 8 project where we have created a component for the editors to use.

A component takes **Datasource** of "Datasource-Folder" with X numbers of "Datasource-Item" below.

The tree looks like this:

- Globals

  - Datasource Folder

    - Datasource Item1
    - Datasource Item2
    - Datasource Item3
    - Datasource Item4

The user can change and add a datasource item with the **Experience Editor**.

Now the issue. In the **Experience Editor** the user can edit the Datasource Item's fields, i.e. he can edit image, text, general link field of this Datasource Item. If they save it I can see saved data in the `master` database. But when the user is publishing the Context Item from the **Experience Editor**, then the datasource items are not publishing. Is that a Sitecore bug?

I have also referenced [this](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/1210). But my question is if it's possible without customizing the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using publishing related items option also when publishing ? publishing context item only will not publish your datasource items

Comment: Yes I have checked related item checkbox.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not possible without custom code.

And to be honest, I don't think this is really what should come out of the box with Sitecore. Your component uses `Datasource Folder` item as datasource and that datasource **will** be published. And it's your own code which takes children of that datasource and uses them to display some content.

That's why I would say that you need to write your own code (or find some existing solution in the net) for publishing those items which are required by your component.

Comment: You could use a template like a marker interface, such as BasePublishChildren, and if an item of this template was published a custom step in the publishing pipeline could then add the children of the item into the publish queue too.

Comment: @Kasaku you're right, that's one of the options. Still, there has to be custom code added. There is no way of achieving what's in the question without coding.

Comment: Oh yes, wasn't disagreeing, just taking your answer and adding more thoughts! :)

Comment: @MarekMusielak but Datasource Children also related to that Datasource Folder, so it should publish them as well.

Comment: I don't think it works that way. It does not consider children as __related__ items. It would have to republish whole database if children and parents and their children and parents where considered as __related__. See https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/publishing/publish_an_item_to_your_website

Comment: @GauravAgarwal - That's how it is in your solution but not necessarily in all others. What if you had referenced another page as your datasource, should it publish all children too? Related goes by direct item references but it doesn't spider out from there to find other content.

Comment: I have raised a ticket to Sitecore Support..waiting for the answer.